# Does Swift init(count:, repeatedValue:) work?

Tags: string, swift, swift-playground

Tested this from the reference: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift

```
var string = String(count: 5, repeatedValue: "a")
// string is "aaaaa"
```

I got this error:

> Playground execution failed: error: :5:14: error: could not find an overload for 'init' that accepts the supplied arguments
>   var string = String(count: 5, repeatedValue: "a")

Does this actually work?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It seems that you have to explicitly pass in a Character type to it to function. This works for me.

```
let char = Character("a")
let string = String(count: 5, repeatedValue: char)
```

Although, there may be bug mixed in with all this as well. I believe the way you were doing this should have worked on its own. And I can't seem to get code completion on this initializer at all.

Edit: I'm going with bug. The following compiles just fine.

```
let array = Array(count: 5, repeatedValue: "a")
```

Comment: This works! It is weird that Swift Reference Guide got such a big mistake.

Comment: Seems like repeatedValue has to be a Character type, but there's no obvious way of making a character literal in Swift (in C, you'd use single quotes rather than double quotes.)

Comment: The guide is not broken, the type inference engine is.  Subscripting is a prime example where it falls flat on its face despite having  really explicit types.

Comment: Using Swift 3 with Xcode 8.1 the syntax has changed and in this case would be: let array = Array(repeating: "a", count: 5)

Answer (score 13):

For the benefit of future searchers: as of Swift 3, use `init(repeating:count:)`.

```
let sososo = String(repeating: "so", count: 3)
```

Comment: Thankfully, this updated initializer also accepts Strings instead of Characters.

Answer (score 6):

This works just fine :

```
var str9 = String(count: 5,repeatedValue: Character("c"))
```

Comment: Yes, but it is basically the same answer as above.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone in swift 3.x its now something like this this will work like a charm.

```
var string = String(repeating: "a", count: 5)
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question and already has an answer. However I think I know **why** `String(count: 5, repeatedValue: "a")` does not work.

The thing is `String` has two similar looking [initialisers](http://swiftdoc.org/v2.2/type/String/#init-count_-int-repeatedvalue_-character):

```
init(count: Int, repeatedValue: Character)
init(count: Int, repeatedValue: UnicodeScalar)
```

So in this case compiler can't tell whether a literal is a `Character` or `UnicodeScalar`, hence compile time error if you don't pass explicit `Character`. To confirm that `"a"` can be interpreted as `UnicodeScalar` you can check that this line compiles:

```
let a: UnicodeScalar = "a"
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 3:**

```
var array = Array(repeating: 0, count: 5)
```

Output: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]