# Repeating String in Swift

Tags: swift, function, swift2, repeat

I'm tasked with creating a function that takes two parameters of a string and int that will return a string that repeats the string parameter the int's number of times. This is what I came up with but getting an error. BTW, this is on CodeCardio that I do at work so I haven't been able to test it out in Xcode (my work sucks and uses Windows)

```
func repeater(aString: String, withNumber: Int) -> String {
    let repeatedString = String(count: withNumber, repeatedValue: aString)
    return repeatedString
}
```

Answer (score 13):

```
String(count: withNumber, repeatedValue: aString)
```

Is used to instantiate an string with a repeated character: [Does Swift init(count:, repeatedValue:) work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24463155/does-swift-initcount-repeatedvalue-work)

Instead do

```
func repeater(string: String, withNumber number: Int) -> String {
    var repeatedString = String()
    for i in 0..<number {
        repeatedString += string
    }
    return repeatedString
}
```

Comment: Oh, I see how that repeatedValue wouldn't work then. Looking over the function you put I can't see why that wouldn't work, but it's also not allowing it. The error it's giving is "unexpected identifier". I've just concluded that CodeCardio isn't up to date with Swift 2 yet so that's why it's giving me random errors.

Answer (score 8):

As of Swift 3, `init(repeating:count:)` can take String arguments as well.

```
var repeatingString = String(repeating: "ab", count: 7)
print(repeatingString) // ababababababab
```

Try this:

```
func repeater(aString: String, withNumber: Int) -> String {
    let repeatedString = String(repeating: aString, count: withNumber)
    return repeatedString
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The type of argument `repeatedValue` of `String(count: repeatedValue: aCharacter)` is a single `Character` rather than `String`.

You could use `Array(count: withNumber, repeatedValue: aString)` and join the items

```
func repeater(aString: String, withNumber: UInt) -> String {
  let repeatedArray = Array(count: Int(withNumber), repeatedValue: aString)
  return repeatedArray.joinWithSeparator("")
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! The function you put is also returning an error but I can't see why it would. I've just concluded that CodeCardio isn't up to date with Swift 2 yet so that's why it's giving me random errors.

Comment: I'm sure it does, I just try to look for ways to practice coding while at work, but I don't think this website will work for Swift just yet.

Comment: @NicLaughter CodeCardio use javasript, html and css :-O

Comment: ugh, well that makes sense. Now just to slap the person that suggested I use it for Swift exercises.

Comment: @NicLaughter try http://iswift.org/playground or https://swiftlang.ng.bluemix.net/#/repl

Comment: there are two issues now. a) it does't compile with error: cannot convert value of type 'UInt' to expected argument type 'Int'. b) if you change your code to Array(count: Int(withNumber), repeatedValue: aString), than let s = repeater("", withNumber: UInt.max) will crash ... :-)

Comment: @user3441734 Right, I fixed that (not the `UInt.max` "issue")

Comment: i have a lot of such issues in my own code, that is why i noted that mixing Int and UInt is nightmare for me ..

Comment: It's worth it to avoid any type check at runtime which can be evaluated at compile time

Answer (score 4):

You can just do this:

```
func repeater(aString string: String, withNumber number: Int) -> String {
    return [String](count: number, repeatedValue: string).reduce("", combine: +)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I slightly modify Tanguy's answer. Now, the function will not crash if the second parameter is less than 0, but returns an empty string

```
func repeate(string: String,  times: Int) -> String {
    var repeatedString = ""
    var n = times
    while n > 0 {
        repeatedString += string
        n -= 1
    }
    return repeatedString
}
```

the same issue has Vadian's answer, checking the parameter and returning early with "" is probably the best solution. I personally prefer Vadian's approach.

Comment: I changed the type in my answer to `UInt` ;-)

Comment: @vadian :-) so simple ...upvoted!  (sometimes mixing Int, UInt etc is nightmare for swift's programmer)

Answer (score 1):

```
func repeatAString(anyString: String, numberOfTimes: Int) ->String
{
    var returnString: String = String()
    for _ in 1...numberOfTimes 
    {
        returnString = returnString.stringByAppendingString(anyString)
    }
    return returnString
}
```

Hi I have used stringByappendingString to solve this one. I see you have plenty of answers but no-one has suggested that so thought Id put it out there. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Swift 5:

```
extension String {
    func repeater(by count: Int) -> String {
        return String(repeating: self, count: count)
    }
}
```

Calling: "testString".repeater(by: counter)

Answer (score 0):

```
func repeater(aString: String, withNumber: Int) -> String 
{
var repeatedString=""
for var index = 0; index < withNumber; ++index 
   {
     repeatedString=repeatedString+aString
   }
return repeatedString
}
```

for Function Call i use:
 print(repeater("String",withNumber: 5))

Comment: I'm also pretty sure that C-style for looks are going away in Swift 3